# Обновления скомпилированного сайта

Tags: веб-программирование

Если сайт написан на интерпретируемом языке (PHP например), то внести изменение не составляет труда: достаточно просто отредактировать определенный файл сразу на сервере.

А если сайт написан на компилируемом языке (C#), то чтобы изменить логику приложения, нужно редактировать исходный код, заново компилировать и загружать на сервер, правильно?

Answer (score 4):

Вы суслика видите? Нет?! А он есть!

Где вы видели скомпилированные бинарники, которые получаются при компиляции сайта, и которые куда-то надо загружать?

Что характерно, не такой уж он вообще и компилируемый, этот C#. JIT-компиляция и интерпретация - сильно схожие вещи. JIT-компиляцию можно рассматривать как один из подходов к интерпретации (которая есть дело очень сложное и непосвященным малопонятное, вот я лично не берусь в него лезть, хотя и занимаюсь Development Tools Development на одной из своих работ, но то несколько другое, алгоритмики разбора кода там мало)
Что характерно, реально компилируемые языки в вебе на бек-енде обычно не используются.